flutter can run on android emulator but cannot build the apk
I'm working with Flutter on Android Studio, and I can run and hot reload my app on an Android emulator without any issues. However, the second try to build an APK, I encounter an error with the code '1' and the following message in the console:
"[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network."
I've tried enabling and disabling my VPN, but the issue persists. I managed to download the files that Gradle failed to download, but I'm unsure of how to utilize them.
Could someone help me on resolving this issue and successfully building an APK with Flutter?

You must be from Iran
Due to USA sanctions, we cannot use these websites freely, so u have to set up a VPN or DNS.
I suggest you:

Use a VPN that opens android developer website.

If u dont have access to VPN, check shecan



hey amirhossein thanks for the guidance. yes im from iran and my vpn opens android developer but it's proxy based and i think that is the problem i tried shecan and it also fails but slower
